# Hiding image target?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, unity3d-2dtools, msbuildcommunitytasks

How to hide image target while objects get detected in unity using VuforiaAPI

There is only one answer I found but didn't know how to implement it.
"Take a look at our Occlusion Management sample. The effect that you're looking for requires a shader applied to a mesh that will create the illusion that the target surface is transparent. The OM sample uses a cube, but the same effect can be applied to a plane - try adding a plane to the OM scene and add the same shader and shader setup script that is used for the box mesh."

Comment: Can you tell what shader are you using on the plane you are using as image target?

Comment: The shader is Unlit/texture

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Material for your plane and to that material change the shader to **Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Cutout/Diffuse** . Now you can select the mainColor and change the aplha value in color picker window to 0. This will hide your image.

Comment: From this the plane color will be visible but I want to completely hide the Image target, so if person see the image it will make illusion that there is no image target.

Comment: why the plaen color will be visible?

Answer (score 0):

by doing what u told, the effect of such would be like this and if I set alpha value 0 than no plane is visible but I want to hide my cylinder or image target
So if any one see that it create illusion that I m holding nothing

[image]